# Create beautiful image upload in configuration magento 2

Tags: magento2, configuration, magento-2.0, image-upload

add image in create new product
[image]

How to make an similar image upload in configuration instead of [image]

In add product, it uses phtml file. In configuration, it uses xml file.

Comment: J.John did you find the solution as mentioned in you question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In `system.xml` you should add this code below:

```
<field id="upload_image_id" translate="label comment" type="image" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Select Image</label>
    <backend_model>NameSpace\YourModule\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
    <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">yourfolder</base_url>
</field>
```

And you should create custom model using in `system.xml`:

> NameSpace\YourModule\Model\Config\Backend\Image.php

```
<?php

namespace NameSpace\YourModule\Model\Config\Backend;

class Image extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image
{
    /**
     * The tail part of directory path for uploading
     *
     */
    const UPLOAD_DIR = 'yourfolder'; // Folder save image

    /**
     * Return path to directory for upload file
     *
     * @return string
     * @throw \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _getUploadDir()
    {
        return $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($this->_appendScopeInfo(self::UPLOAD_DIR));
    }

    /**
     * Makes a decision about whether to add info about the scope.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _addWhetherScopeInfo()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for allowed extensions of uploaded files.
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    protected function _getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'svg'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but your answer is create default image upload as pure html.

I want to use customize image button similar image upload in add product.

Comment: My code use in Configuration, Are you understand ?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you code. And I know what it does.

I wonder there is a way create a image upload button similar in add product. Because I see default button is not beautiful.

Comment: can this be used in admin form as well? if not what's the way to do it?

Comment: I need to add multiple images to system config. How it possible?

Comment: is it possible to configure it so it saves full path to file to db?

Comment: How do I set the field name? I'm trying to use this code in a custom model!

Comment: how can i view the image in frontend? i have tried to call the helper with the correct path but the image never loads up

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted answer worked for me. For some reason the validation does not work. I ended up using a custom `Config\Backend\Image` file.

In my `system.xml` I've added the image field below

```
<field id="my_image_field" translate="label" sortOrder="1" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Image" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>My Image</label>
    <backend_model>Vendor\Package\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
    <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">my_image_folder</base_url>
    <validate>required-entry</validate>
    <upload_dir config="system" scope_info="1">my_image_folder</upload_dir>
</field>
```

Then, as you can tell, I've created the file "`Vendor\Package\Model\Config\Backend\Image`" with the following content:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Package\Model\Config\Backend;

class Image extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File
{
    protected function _getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'svg'];
    }
}
```

FIY, the image will be saved in `magento_root/pub/media/my_image_folder`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: how can i view the image in frontend? i have tried to call the helper with the correct path but the image never loads up

Comment: @jibingeorge Just check the media directory and see what path is the image located at and refer the same in frontend.

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe something too late but someone else can use it**

You can use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Media\Image and binding this to your config form by hidden input.

Try the following code created by me.

Create a Vendor\Module\Block\Data\Form\Element\ImageUploader

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Data\Form\Element;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\Math\Random;
use Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class ImageUploader extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{
    public function __construct(
        Factory $factoryElement,
        CollectionFactory $factoryCollection,
        Escaper $escaper,
        $data = [],
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\File\Mime $mime,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        parent::__construct(
            $factoryElement,
            $factoryCollection,
            $escaper,
            $data
        );
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->mime = $mime;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::ROOT);
    }

    public function getElementHtml(){
        
        $initData = [
            'config' => [
                'initialMediaGalleryOpenSubpath' => 'wysiwyg',
                'previewTmpl' => 'Magento_PageBuilder/form/element/uploader/preview',
                'uploaderConfig' => [
                    'url' => 'pagebuilder/contenttype/image_upload',
                ],
            ]
        ];

        $data = array_replace_recursive($initData, $this->getData());
        $uiComponent = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Media\Image::class);
        $uiComponent->setData($data);
        $uiComponent->prepare();
        $this->setData($uiComponent->getData());

        return '<div id="content_img_id" data-bind="scope:\'customImageUploader\'">' .
                    '<input type="hidden" name="'.$this->getName().'"data-bind="value: $data.value()[0] ? $data.value()[0][\'url\'] : \'\'" />' .
                    '<!-- ko template: $data.elementTmpl --><!-- /ko -->' .
                    '<script type="text/x-magento-init">'.
                        '{
                            "#content_img_id": {
                                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                                    "components": {
                                        "customImageUploader": {
                                            "component": "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/image-uploader",
                                            "elementTmpl": "ui/form/element/uploader/image",
                                            "config": '.json_encode($this->getConfig()).',
                                            "value": '.json_encode($this->getValue()).',
                                            "dataScope": "customImageUploader"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }'.
                    '</script>' .
                '</div>';
    }

    public function getValue(){
        $filePath = parent::getValue();
        $newfilePath = explode('/', $filePath);
        unset($newfilePath[0], $newfilePath[1]);
        $newfilePath = implode('/', $newfilePath);
        $image = [];
        if ($newfilePath && $this->mediaDirectory->isExist($newfilePath)) {
            $stat = $this->mediaDirectory->stat($newfilePath);
            $mime = $this->mime->getMimeType($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($newfilePath));
            $image[0]['name'] = basename($newfilePath);
            $image[0]['url'] = $filePath;
            $image[0]['size'] = isset($stat) ? $stat['size'] : 0;
            $image[0]['type'] = $mime;
        }
        return $image;
    }
}
```

In your system.xml add this field like this:

```
<field id="field_name" translate="label" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Data\Form\Element\ImageUploader" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>Image</label>
</field>
```