# Magento 2 PHP Fatal error: Class not found when compiling

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, setup-di-compile

When I compile I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class
> 'Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Image\Upload' not found
> in
> /var/www/html/magento/app/code/Plazathemes/Override/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Image/Upload.php
> on line 11

**EDIT with the code:**

[image]

Still unable to fix can someone write the soltion to fix this.

Comment: Are you sure all composer packages are installed? If something is corrupt in your composer and you do composer install/update it won't fix it. You have to force reinstall that package. Try cleaning the vendor folder and run composer install or composer update

Comment: Can you please provide the steps to follow to do this.

Comment: Did you remove `var/di`, `var/generation` and try run di compile again?

Comment: Clear cache and generated files and again recompile. Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Seem that you're trying to override the class `Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Image\Upload`. So, make sure your custom class will extend from this class.

```
class Upload extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Image\Upload {
   ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are getting the error itself but if i may suggest just making your file like this?

```
    namespace ....
    use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader;

    class Upload extends Action{

        /**
         * Image uploader
         *
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader
         */
        protected $imageUploader;

        /**
         * Upload constructor.
         *
         * @param Action\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
         */
        public function __construct(
            Action\Context $context,
            ImageUploader $imageUploader
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
        }

    public function execute(){
    ....
    }

    }
```

I also suggest you use the Magento image uploader instead of the category uploader unless that is really your intention.
Like here
[Create beautiful image upload in configuration magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91905/create-beautiful-image-upload-in-configuration-magento-2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Just a comment. Since i do not know the intend or the page where you are using this i can not provide a specific solution but i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a alias name for the extended class - as shown below:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Image\Upload as CatalogImageUopload

class Upload extends CatalogImageUopload
{
 -----write your code here---
}
```