# Direct use of $_FILES Superglobal detected. In magento 2

Tags: magento2, forms, post-data

Direct use of $_FILES Superglobal detected.

I have Used for get image file in backend.

```
 protected function getTmpFileName()
{
    $tmpName = null;
    if (isset($_FILES['groups'])) {
        $tmpName = $_FILES['groups']['tmp_name'][$this->getGroupId()]['fields'][$this->getField()]['value'];
    } else {
        $tmpName = is_array($this->getValue()) ? $this->getValue()['tmp_name'] : null;
    }
    return $tmpName;
}
```

Comment: Why and where you use?

Comment: where and then you see this error ?

Comment: this is error , because use superglobal like ( $_POST, $_GET,$_FILES etc.) isn`t good practice!

Comment: you try get image of the product ?

Comment: yes, which image you want to get? from where ?

Comment: don`t understood , image from configurations ? which configurations ? which image ?

Comment: I have created Image filed for image uploading

Comment: in system/configurations ? right ?

Comment: yes  system/configurations

Answer (score 1):

If you are using $_FILES in magento 2 code anywhere that will give you error because PHP $_FILES tag that doesn’t support directly so you need to use that magento 2 own code.

do something like this :

```
$uploader = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',['fileId' => 'file_name']);

 // print_r($uploader->validateFile());

                                   //$ffgko = $_FILES['file_name']['name'];

                                   $fInam = $uploader->validateFile();

                                   $ffgko = $fInam['name'];
```

using of object manger is not good practice too, but you can use it for testing, and after replace it with decency injection

or check here :
[Create beautiful image upload in configuration magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91905/create-beautiful-image-upload-in-configuration-magento-2)

and here you can check good detail explanation how to do that! :
https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/add-image-upload-in-configuration-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to use a custom backend model for image upload on system.xml,
then you can try this

```
class Image extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image{

    protected function getTmpFileName(){

        //$path = 'sectionId/groupId/fieldId' from system.xml
        return $this->_requestData->getTmpName($path);
    }
}
```